# JavaScript: How to check if a array object contain specific values

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have this array:

```js
[
  {
    "active": true,
    "name": "agency one"
  },
  {
    "active": false,
    "name": "agency two"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "name": "agency three"
  },
  {
    "active": false,
    "name": "agency four"
  }
]
```

And some data like this:

```js
{
    "domain": "agency one",
    "url": "https://....",
    "title": "some title",
    "img": "https://.....jpg",
    "tag": "some tag",
}
```

How can I check if agancy is active show data?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: It seems very simple. Did you try using for each loop and just check if active is true and then display data. What is the issue u r facing ?

Comment: I suggest reviewing the `.find()`, `.some()`, and `.filter()` Array prototype methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use methods like:

.find()

.filter()

.findIndex()

```
const firstActiveAgency = arr.find(item => item.active);

const allActiveAgencies = arr.filter(item => item.active);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming variable `agencies` holds the array included in your post:

```
const activeAgencies = agencies.filter(agency => {
    return agency.active === true
  })
```

Then `activeAgencies` would be a new array holding only the agency objects marked active.

Answer (score 1):

use .filter()

```
console.log(array.filter(items => {
  return items.active === true
//should return every "active that is set to true"
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Final answer to the question:

```js
let agenciesList = 
[
  {
    "active": true,
    "name": "agency one"
  },
  {
    "active": false,
    "name": "agency two"
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "name": "agency three"
  },
  {
    "active": false,
    "name": "agency four"
  }
];

let allActiveAgencies = agenciesList.filter(item => item.active);

let newArray = allActiveAgencies.map(item => item.name);

console.log(newArray); // ["agency one","agency three"]
console.log(newArray.includes("agency one")); // true
```